# VBA, Data into Rows instead of Columns and Filldown?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing to column C, but the data goes ex: C1:X1, instead I would like it by row. (ex: C1:C25)  I would like it to be transposed vertically down the rows instead of horizontally.

The problem with this is I want the columns A&B to be filled down with this transposition in unisen. So A1:A25 would have the file name and C1:c25 would have my headers.

As I start to add more columns I would like to be able to add more columns and fill down to these aswell. (only filldown columns A and B)

any Ideas?

Code:

```
  Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim lOutputCol As Long


'Loop through the worksheets in the current workbook.
For iIndex = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count

    'Set the current worksheet
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(iIndex)

    'List out the workbook and worksheet names
    wsReport.Range("A" & lRow).Value = wb.Name
    wsReport.Range("B" & lRow).Value = ws.Name

    'Start a counter of the columns that we are writing to
    lOutputCol = 3

    'Loop through the columns.
    For lCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        'Write the header
        wsReport.Range(Col_Letter(lOutputCol) & lRow).Value = ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value

        'Increment our column counters.
        lOutputCol = lOutputCol + 1
    Next lCol

    'Increment the row we are writing to
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next iIndex
```

Function:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to change the  lOutputCol from an incremented value to a static columnC.  And you will have to add a lRow count increment inside the loop.

Change

```
'Loop through the columns.
For lCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    'Write the headers
    wsReport.Range(Col_Letter(lOutputCol) & lRow).Value = ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value

    'Increment our column counters.
    lOutputCol = lOutputCol + 1
Next lCol
```

to

```
'Loop through the columns.
For lCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'List out the workbook and worksheet names
    wsReport.Range("A" & lRow).Value = wb.Name
    wsReport.Range("B" & lRow).Value = ws.Name

    'Write the headers
    wsReport.Range("C" & lRow).Value = ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value

    'Increment our column counters.
    lOutputCol = lOutputCol + 1

    'Increment the row we are writing to
    lRow = lRow + 1

Next lCol
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, again. Where do I add fill down in here to fill down sheet and wb name?

Comment: I changed my answer a bit. If I understand what you are looking for, move the `wsReport.Range("A" & lRow).Value = wb.Name` and `wsReport.Range("B" & lRow).Value = ws.Name` inside the loop

Comment: Awesome, so smart, just for future reference, if I want to add additional things such as other column extract data, can this be done easily or does the rest of the macro change if I need additional data extracted?

Comment: If you want to write out some other data you can just add another line like. `wsReport.Range("D" & lRow).Value = "someOtherData`

Comment: i know I marked this as correct, so If I wanted to extract data from a certain header in file and filter it for unique values and throw it into my next column on my reconciliation sheet, can this be done?